# How to import Live Photos from Finder to Photos.app?

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, photos, photos.app

I only use Photos.app as a browser of all my images.

I unselected the *copy items to the Photos library* so my files can live in my hard drive and I don't duplicate them inside the Photos Library.photoslibrary archive.

I use Image Capture to import the iPhone pictures to a folder and after I used to imported to Photos.app and everything was great.

But now with Live photos I get two files for each picture, the picture and the little movie that makes the Live part possible. The problem is that if I try to import them to Photos.app, it doesn't recognise them.

Is there any way to import the picture with the Live functionality to the app **without duplicating the content**?

Comment: Have you ever figured out how to get this to work?

Comment: Yes! I just added the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to import the two files of the same picture (the photo and the video) with the same name.

Photos will recognise them as a live picture then.

Comment: Thanks. In retrospect, it seems like a no-brainer. But I've been quite frustrated with Photos.app and other Apple tech (coming from a long time Apple user too) not working "as expected" recently that I figured a solution "that simple" surely wouldn't work. This taught me not to assume (again).

Answer (score 0):

Which version of macOS are you using? This is supposed to work on Sierra.

I cannot test this because my iPhone cannot take Live Photos. Try to download the photos from your iPhone by connecting it to a USB port of your Mac and importing directly to Photos.

The safest way to transfer Live Photos is to use iCloud Photo Library and let the Mac sync with iCloud.